# How can I disable edits for block of text in QPlainTextEdit?

Tags: c++, qt, keypress, qwidget, qplaintextedit

I am making a component based on QPlainTextEdit. I would like to make portions of text readonly (but still allow selections, navigations and clipboard etc).

I can detect the keypress event and suppress it but I need a condition to do this on. Is there a way to block edits without having to check for different keys, combinations etc (that might be different on each platform)?

Comment: Use `QPlainTextEdit::setReadOnly(true);`. User cannot modify text, but can still select, copy, navigate, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I would still like portions of the text to be editable but I suppose I could set it to readonly when the cursor is placed within the part that I want to be readonly and not when anywhere else in the document.